# What is the biology behind a skin "mole"?

Tags: human-biology

Are the dark marks aka "moles" on our skin a patch of dead cells? If so, why is it not cleared over time? In a (probably) similar vein, why do scar marks from injuries remain long after new cells replace the dead cells?

[Feel free to edit out the second question if the answers are unrelated]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [mole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanocytic_nevus) is simply a benign tumour, i.e. a proliferated cell growth that hasn’t become cancerous. So moles are *not* dead cells, they are very much alive. The colour is caused by a high concentration of the melanin, which is also responsible for normal darker skin.

Since moles are tumours, they can – but in most cases don’t – give rise to [melanomas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanoma), malignant skin tumours, when they lose susceptibility to cell growth regulation and start invading surrounding tissue.

[Scar tissue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scar) is entirely unrelated and due to regular regrowth of epithelial cells after injury forming a linear collagen structure (as opposed to the skin’s normal collagen structure, which resembles a “weaved“ structure).

Answer (score 0):

A Mole may be a Hamartoma or a benign tumor. A congenital mole is usually a hamartoma, while acquired mole a benign tumor. In a few people mole very slowly grow in size.